# How to link a page of a particular date

Tags: php, jquery

How to link a page using date picker for a particular date i.e today is 25/2/2015 and i updated something on a page and after few days if someone click on that date i.e. on 25/2/2015, then how will someone able to see that page?

Comment: Too vague, too broad, no code provided, one long sentence without punctuation... you'll have a hard time getting an answer.

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned above I think Jeremy is right. Jokes apart. I think you are talking about the data flow design of the overall form that will query into the database to find out how to many entries are there in the database for that date. follow a few of these steps :

1. Create a table with needed columns also having "created on" column
2. Create a "html form" having date as input and post the data from that form to a PHP page.
3. On the PHP page convert the date format to MySQL format and then query. Redirect or display the output as desired.